# How to import a .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, import, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running MySQL on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS and unfortunately I've been experiencing serious problems when it comes to importing a sql file.

What I actually do:

1) I move to the directory containing the sql file which is called: bk.sql

2) Then I type :

`mysql -u root -p` (and then I enter the root password and everything goes smoothly)

3) I use this command to do the import operation (assuming that password =123m Database name = Mydb sql file = bk.sql)

```
mysql -u root -p 123m Mydb < bk.sql;
```

What I get is :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 

corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root 

-p 123m Mydb < bk.sql' at line 1
```

Is the import procedure correct?

Comment: Remove the space between -p and the password

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are running the mysql import command from the mysql prompt which is not right.

You don't need to do step 2. Just do steps 1 and 3.

Comment: Or, from the MySQL prompt, run  `source bk.sql` to have it parse the file.

Comment: If I only do steps 1 and 3 I get a very long output ...like mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
Copyright 2000-2008 MySQL AB, 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY....et  Then within the mysql prompt if I type show databases; I don't see Mydb...

Comment: does it work if you do step 1 and 2, and then type `source bk.sql` as Konerak suggested?

Comment: If I do steps 1 and 2 and then type source bk.sql I get a list of Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) and ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: Problem solved. I first created a database, then I typed : mysql -u root -p -h localhost Db_created < bk.sql Now Db_created is visible if the show dataabses command is issued...

Answer (score 4):

Do this, and you will have it.

```
mysql -u root -ptoor -h localhost database_in_mysql < local_sql_file.sql
mysql> show databases;

mysql> use meow;
mysql> select * from customers_meow;
```

and you'll see all the tables, bingo !
ch33rs.

Answer (score 0):

First enter this.. in cmd or terminal...

```
mysql -u root -p Mydb < bk.sql
```

Then it ask password

```
Password : 123m
```

Now wait .. i will take several time ..
thats all...