# how to import sql file in command prompt

Tags: mysql

i am trying to import sql file through putty

below are my details of DB 
dbname - test, 
password - test123, 
username -utest,

i tried the below code

```
mysql -u utest -p test123 test< /home/path/public_html/file.sql
```

when i run this command i saw a error message

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u utest -p test123  test < file' at line 1`

please suggest how to import sql file

Thank Sanjib

Comment: there should not be a space between `-p` and `test123`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316507/how-to-import-a-sql-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
mysql -utest -ptest123  test < /home/path/public_html/file.sql
```

and make sure that you run this command from your console not in mysql

if you are in mysql prompt than it would be somehting like this

```
mysql> use test;
mysql> source /home/path/public_html/file.sql;
```

OR

```
 mysql>SET autocommit=0; source /home/path/public_html/file.sql; COMMIT;
```

Comment: it works fine, one question to you. I rememebr, i have tried the same command and it was successfully imported. But today  i don't understand why not imported

Comment: may be you are missing some minor thing :)

Comment: @psanjb: Maybe you had hit CTRL+D to exit mysql first.

Comment: @psanjib please mark it as correct so that other user can get the help from your question

Answer (score 2):

You should run this command in your console, outside of the mysql tool.